# Prove that $f(z)$ is of the $Ce^{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function, such that  : $|f(z)|\geq e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)}$.

Prove that there is a constant $C$ such that  $f(z)=Ce^{z}$.

I think I need to work with Liouville's theorem and the fact that every Holomorphic function is a power series.

Any help?

Comment: What is $x$? $\!\,$

Comment: sorry...that's a $z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $x$ is the typo of $z$. Since $|f(z)|\ge e^{\operatorname{Re}z} =|e^z|$, $|f(z)e^{-z}|\ge 1$ so $f(z)e^{-z}$ has no zero and so its reciprocal is also analytic. Thus $|e^z/f(z)|\le 1$ so you can apply the Liouville's theorem.